# Solving equation (Fractional power)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this equation?

$$0.064t^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{2}{375}t^3=0$$

I'm solving one mechanic question and I'm stuck in this step. The answers are $0$ and $144$.

Comment: it is equivalent to $$(0.064)^2t^5=\left(\frac{2}{375}\right)^2t^6$$

Comment: Try to Factor out a $t^2$, this gives the zero $t=0$, then solve for a zero in the remaining term

Comment: i have found the two solutions $0.,144,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0.064t^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{2}{375}t^3=0$$
or$$t^{\frac{5}{2}}(0.064-\frac{2}{375}t^{\frac{1}{2}})=0$$

These give $$t=0$$ and $$t^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{0.064\times 375}{2}=12 \Rightarrow t=144$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the following equation:

$$0.064t^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{2}{375}t^3=0$$

The first step would be to factor out any common terms in both terms of the equation. In this case, we can see that it would be $t^{\frac{5}{2}}$.

Therefore, factoring, we get:

$$t^{\frac{5}{2}}\left(0.064 - \frac{2}{375}t^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) = 0$$

As we can see there are two equations that could make this true.

The first one is:

$$t^{\frac{5}{2}} = 0$$

The only solution that is valid here is $t = 0$.

The second one is:

$$\left(0.064 - \frac{2}{375}t^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) = 0$$

Solving, we get that:

$$\frac{2}{375}t^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0.064$$
$$t^{\frac{1}{2}} = 12$$'
$$\left(t^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2 = (12)^2$$
$$t = 144$$

Answer (score 0):

Exclude $t^{5/2}$ from the equation ($t=0$).
Then $$0.064=2\frac{\sqrt{t}}{375}$$
So $\sqrt t=0.064*375/2=12$
$$t=12^2=144$$

Answer (score 0):

$$0.064t^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{2}{375}t^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{8t^{\frac{5}{2}}}{125}-\frac{2t^3}{375}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{8t^{\frac{5}{2}}}{125}=\frac{2t^3}{375}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{64t^5}{15625}=\frac{4t^6}{140625}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{64t^5}{15625}-\frac{4t^6}{140625}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{4t^5\left(t-144\right)}{140625}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$t^5\left(t-144\right)=0$$

So:

- $$t^5=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$t=0$$
- $$t-144=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$t=144$$